# Eureka: Ambiguous reference to member '+++'

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I have the following exemplary form setup:

```
let testForm = Form()

testForm +++ Section()
<<< PushRow().cellSetup( { (cell, row) in
    row.title = "foo"
})
+++ Section()
```

The line `testForm +++ Section()` causes the error `Ambiguous reference to member '+++'`. When I remove the cellSetup call the error disappears. What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error. PushRow is a generic type. As such I have to declare it as

```
PushRow<String>()
```

Comment: elegant answer.